# Can server/client recv EAGAIN while data is being read?

Tags: tcp, nonblocking

For a TCP connection, operating in Non-blocking mode on both client and server-side.

Assume that server has sent 10bytes successfully in one shot, Can the client receive the data in (2bytes,2bytes, EAGAIN, 8bytes) chunks? or will the client will always receive data in (2bytes,2bytes,8bytes)(without EAGAIN). Can there be an EAGAIN in between in any case?

Comment: `EAGAIN` only occurs in non-blocking mode. You can receive any number of bytes from 1 to the supplied buffer size. or `EAGAIN` if you're in non-blocking mode and there is no data. But if you're in non-blocking mode you should be using `select()` and friends to tell you when to read: you should never see `EAGAIN` in correctly written code.

Comment: I am using epoll.
So, once `10 bytes` data is sent successfully by the server, client socket will become readable using epoll, then I will use recv() command to read as much data is possible in a loop.  





My question if the server has sent 10 bytes of data. Will the client get all the 10bytes in one go maybe in (2bytes, 2bytes, 8bytes) chunks or I can get intermittent `EAGAIN` in between after reading 4 bytes.(2bytes, 2bytes) and then Epoll will again trigger read event for next 
6 bytes of data later?

Comment: Well you *shouldn't* be 'us[ing] `recv()` command to read as much data is possible in a loop'. There is no purpose in this. You should be using `epoll()` to tell you when the socket is next ready to be read. Otherwise you are just smoking the CPU to no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: Let's say the first few bytes(uint32) denotes how much data needs to be read from the socket and the value of this is 10 bytes so while reading these 10 bytes, Can get intermittent EAGAIN?